# WP Donation Form with custom payment API

Tags: plugins, forms, api

I want to know if there's a plug-in out there which gives you the possibility to create a donation form and to use a custom payment gateway(not only Stripe,PayPal, etc).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[GiveWP](http://givewp.com/) allows you to create [your own payment gateway](https://givewp.com/documentation/developers/how-to-build-a-gateway-add-on-for-givewp/). It also allows you to track offline donations, like cash or in-person card transactions.